# Should repeat a number of times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is simon_says_spec.rb

```
require simon_says
     describe "repeat" do
        it "should repeat" do
          repeat("hello").should == "hello hello"
        end

        # Wait a second! How can you make the "repeat" method
        # take one *or* two arguments?
        #
        # Hint: *default values*
        it "should repeat a number of times" do
          repeat("hello", 3).should == "hello hello hello"
        end
      end
    end
```

And here is my simon_says.rb

```
def repeat(x,y)
        y.times do print x + ‘ ‘
    end
end
```

After i fixed `def repeat(x,y = 2)` When I run `rake` on window, it works just fine. But when i run `rake` on mac. This is what i got

```
/Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': /Users/thanhnguyen/Downloads/learn_ruby-master/03_simon_says/simon_says.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
/Users/thanhnguyen/Downloads/learn_ruby-master/03_simon_says/simon_says.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/Downloads/learn_ruby-master/03_simon_says/simon_says_spec.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
/Users/thanhnguyen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -S rspec /Users/thanhnguyen/Downloads/learn_ruby-master/03_simon_says/simon_says_spec.rb -I/Users/thanhnguyen/Downloads/learn_ruby-master/03_simon_says -I/Users/thanhnguyen/Downloads/learn_ruby-master/03_simon_says/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed
```

Ive been struggling with this error for couple days but still cannot fix it. I run

```
`gem install spec`
```

i run `bundle install`

This is my system

```
ruby 2.1.1
rails 4.1.1
rvm 1.25.25
bundler 1.6
```

Would somebody plz help?

Comment: Why should only passing in "hello" result in two hello's?

Comment: If you are asking a new question - write it in a new post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below part, you passed only **1** argument instead **2**.

```
describe "repeat" do
        it "should repeat" do
          repeat("hello").should == "hello hello"
          #        ^ why only 1 argument ?
        end
```

As per your code, it should be `repeat("hello", 2).should == "hello hello"`.

As per *commented hints*, you can write also :-

```
def repeat(x, y = 2)
   y.times { print x + ‘ ‘ }
end
```

Now, the test code you wrote, will work without error, with above modified method definition.

```
require simon_says

describe "repeat" do
  it "should repeat" do
    # here you are not passsing the second argument. But *repeat* method has `2`
    # as its default value of the second argument. So no issue will be here.
    repeat("hello").should == "hello hello"
  end

  it "should repeat a number of times" do
    repeat("hello", 3).should == "hello hello hello"
  end
end
```

Read this [*default argument*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+%22default+argument%22) to know, how *default argument* works in Ruby.

Comment: actually, this is a exercise. They gave me the spec file and i suppose to make it run. Thats why i don't understand, the first repeat just 1 argument and then the next one 2 augment. I think it gotta do something with default value which is what it suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Picking up where @Arup left off (you've edited the question with a follow-up)

1. you are using a non-ASCII char `‘` instead of `'` - ruby does not like that.
2. Your code *does not return* the chained text, but rather the number of times you multiplied it (it does print the result though)

   ```
   3.times do '123' end
   # => 3
   ```

   So you test will fail.
   A better way to do that will be

   ```
   y.times.map { x + ' ' }.join
   ```

And in a more ruby way:

```
([x] * y).join(' ')
```

Comment: Ohh! Uri a big mistake I did.. Didn't actually look at the code, only tried to look at the Rspec failure.. I should need to write this in my code itself. I think, without this, the answer is not eligible to accept. +1

Comment: After i rewrite the code, it works with window as well. But i can not make it run on Mac. Although i install all of the gem. Any suggest guys?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the end statement for your do loop.

```
def repeat(x, y = 2)
    y.times do print x + ' ' end
end
```

Comment: The error, OP got not for this. What you told is true. But I think that's typo. Main reason is different.

Comment: Yes I saw that you had added the default not OP, so I removed my comment.  I think you are probably correct.